# Create list of methods and classes C#

Tags: c#, list, loops

I have a .cs file that is filled with classes, and methods inside of said classes. How would one go about creating a list of names of all the methods in the said C# file?

for example, say I have:

```
    public class Trim
{
    public static string TrimEndCustom(string inputString, string charsToTrim)
    {
         //method code here
    }
    public static string TrimStartCustom(string inputString, string charsToTrim)
    {
       //Method Code here
    }
}
       //Next class with more methods
```

My initial thoughts were to loop through all the classes then loop through the methods and add the names, but I am not familiar enough with the syntax of C# to do so. I might be looking at this the wrong way as well.

Essentially my goal is to have a string list of the names of all the methods in my .cs file

Comment: at what time do you need the information?

Comment: and why do you need it, for documentation?

Comment: Do you use XML documentation at all?

Comment: I am just writing a method in a separate program that can read all the method names from a .cs file and populate them in a list. being pretty new to programming I hope that answers some of the questions. I do not use XML documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is collecting these names?  Is this from within a program at runtime?  If so, you can use reflection:

```
List<string> names = new List<string>();
Type t = typeof(Trim);
var methods = t.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

foreach (var method in methods)
{
   string name = method.Name;
   names.Add(name);
}
```

Names will have all of the public static method names; you can change the binding flags to tweak whether you want instance names as well.  Note that some of the syntax may be a little off, but the core is there.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this without using reflection by using [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn). Here is an example method that has one parameter -- the location of a C# source file -- and returns an `IEnumerable<string>` of all of the method names found within that source file:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetMethodNames(string fileName)
{
    var tree = Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(File.ReadAllText(fileName));

    var methods = tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>().ToList();

    foreach (var method in methods)
    {
        yield return method.Identifier.Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

This is convenient, because you don't even have to compile the original *.cs file in order for this to work. Based on the fact that you're trying to build separate program to generate this list of method names, hopefully this will work nicely for you.

Note: You'll need to install the [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/) along with all of its dependencies for this to work. Roslyn is *extremely* powerful -- once you have the syntax tree, you can basically access anything in the file that the C# compiler itself would.